# Show that $\max \left\{\max\{a,b,c\},\max\{d,e\}\right\} = \max\{a,b,c,d,e\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is an exercise from Beckenbach and Bellman. (Chap 3.3)

The hint they give in the answer is:

```
> Consider the representative cases along with the definition of $max\{ \}$
```

Surely this is too simple? (Representing, for example one of the ‘cases’)

Let $a,b,c,d,e = -4,-3,1,5,6$

Thus: $\max \left\{\max\{-4,-3,1\},\max\{5,6\}\right\} = \max \left\{1,6\right\} = 6 = \max \{-4,-3,1,5,6\} $

Or should it be a much more formal approach, like considering if $a < 0$, then $a\le 0$, then $a > 0$ for each of the variables?

Comment: I don't believe that is what the author had in mind. Consider the case where the max is one of $a, b, c$, for example. What is the other case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\max\{\max\{a,b,c\}, \max\{d,e\}\}$, $B=\max\{a,b,c,d,e\}.$ You have to show $A=B.$

Separate into some cases.

**Case I** : the case where $\max\{a,b,c\}=a$ (i.e. $b,c\leqq a$)

If $\max\{d,e\}\leqq a$, then $$A=\max\{\max\{a,b,c\},\max\{d,e\}\}=\max\{a,\max\{d,e\}\}=a,$$ and $B=a$ since $a$ is bigger than any other element, and thus $A=B.$

If $\max\{d,e\}> a$, then $$A=\max\{\max\{a,b,c\}, \max\{d,e\}\}=\max\{a, \max\{d,e\}\}=\max\{d,e\},$$ and $B=\max\{a,b,c,d,e\}=\max\{d,e\}$ since $b,c\leqq a<\max\{d,e\},$ and thus $A=B.$

In the case $\max\{a,b,c\}=b$ and the case $\max\{a,b,c\}=c$, $A=B$ can be proved similarly to **Case I.**

Comment: @ So_M. Thank you for that and I accepted this as the answer.